# What is fastest algorithm for getting relative to image shapes formed by aeries with relatively same colors on the given image?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, image, search

Given image is N*M (R,G,B) pixels like:

[image]

Algorithm should tall us how  to find main image colors like: red and white here.

Aeries with relatively same colors means we search for  (R,G,B) (222, 12, 10) giving for example such step (40,  20, 10 ) so that (199, 32, 5) will count like what we are searching for like:

[image]

Shapes should be defined by array of connected points (x, y) attached to pixels like:

[image]

Pseudo code will work for me as well as any readable code in OO language like Java or C++ (in this 2 I am especially interested)

What algorithm is fastest for getting relative to image shapes formed by aeries with relatively same colors on the given image?

Comment: If step with search for main colors is imposible (meaning will make algorithm so so 2 much slower) than lats asume we have array of colors usual for our enviroments like [(22,222,22), (111,11,11), (222, 12, 10)  and (4,4,4)] so they can be targeted main colors... bad solution but only one I see right now

Comment: You should look into OpenCV, you may find your algorithm there. Also, your question seems to be of rather extensive. Maybe a work-for-hire site like vworker will work better for you.

Comment: Also, to get good results, you probably want to do your calcualtions in a perception-based colorspace. Convert to _Lab_ color space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a warning. You should be carefull with the wording: if you identify the three "main colors" of your image,  you may get the following (code in Mahematica):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look up algorithms for [image segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29).